# Distribution of differences in events of a Poisson distributed variable?

Tags: random-variables, poisson-distribution

A variable $y(t)$, $t=0,1,2,3\cdots $, and $y$ has realisations in $\{0,1,…,20\}$ is Poisson distributed. Is there a form to describe the distribution of difference $y(t)-y(t-1)$ between each realisation?

A plot shows: Both negative and positive changes fit a negative binomial distribution, making the distribution look like a discrete Laplace distribution.

Comment: What is the dependence between them? For example, if $y(t)$ were a Poisson process then the differences would be Poisson distributed. The situation would be very different if they were independent.

Comment: Oh I forgot. It is assumed that the process is time-homogenous. It satisfies the Markov assumption.

Comment: Concerning your answer: $k=y(t)-y(t-1)$  can take negative values. So $P(|y(t)-y(t-1)|=|k|)=\frac{\lambda^{|k|}}{|k|!}e^{-\lambda}$?

Comment: That still doesn't really tell us what the dependence actually is, only that $y(t)$ conditioned on $y(t-1)$ is independent of $y(t-c)$ for all $c>1$.